# Cucumber: Testing all choices in a table

Tags: c#, cucumber

I'm trying to create a test where if a user selects a default setting from the settings page, it will set and display that setting throughout the site. I want my test to run through all examples to be able to test all choices. Is this good or is there a better way to do this? Also, I noticed for each cycle, it does not pick the choices in the table in order. It goes through all of them but picks them randomly somehow. Is there a way to set it to run through each choices in order? Thanks :)

```
Scenario Outline: Setting default gender and size

Given I select a gender <Gender> and size <Size> in the settings page
When I go to any Search page
Then The filter for Gender and Size should always display <Gender> and <Size>

Examples: 
| Gender| Size   |
| Girl  | Small  |
| Girl  | Medium |
| Girl  | Large  |
| Boy   | Small  |
| Boy   | Medium |
| Boy   | Large  |
```